# Javascript assets not loading to deployed Heroku app(Production), but works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, heroku

I have been fighting with this issue for the past two days now and have gotten nowhere, unfortunately. I know this is a regularly asked question but none of the answers I have encountered have helped.

Below shows my assets in Chrome when the application is run locally.

[Assets in Chrome(local)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mqsy.png)

Below are assets in Chrome Production

[Assets in Chrome(production)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcgfE.png)

**What I have tried**

I have tried doing `config.assets.compile = true`

I tried reorganizing my `application.js` file

also `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile` and then deployed to production.

I honestly wish I could remember all the steps i have tried but the ones above are the most reoccurring.

**Code**

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'rubocop', require: false


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end


group :production do
  gem 'mini_racer'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha6'

gem "awesome_print", require:"ap"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'sprockets', '~>3.7.2'
gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
```

**application.js**

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require "tether"
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

**application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Chessapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.serve_static_assets = true
    config.assets.compile = true
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  #config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'chesschessrevolution.herokuapp.com' }

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "chessapp_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chessapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/nav' %>
    <div>
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
        <class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
        <class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

        <%= yield %>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. If the information I provided isn't sufficient please feel free to check out the repository @ [github](https://github.com/chris-campbell/chessapp) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets are loading, the reason why you are not able to see them individually(separate files) in production is because rails precompiles(minimizes) all the assets and puts into a single file.

So if you have look at your application.css and application.js which is getting rendered in production you can see that it contains bootstrap, jquery, jquery-ui etc which you've required in application.js

I had a look at your [application.css](http://rocky-bastion-71544.herokuapp.com/assets/application-8163be3d5159ff9c4e278ad8cc982af8c60b316c2aa5aa186e7a390d5c5bbe00.css) and [application.js](http://rocky-bastion-71544.herokuapp.com/assets/application-75fe0fc8bb34d8db3c2f06ca4840f6f027eb42d61995e4c69e0cd2be02ebea65.js) and it contained all the assets you've required. They are not available anymore probably because you have done re-deployment.

You can learn more about asset pipeline [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks alot! You definitely guided me in the right direction. I looking in the compiled folder provided in chrome source and noticed my code was in fact there. What confuses me is why Javascript works one when locally and another way when in production. But I guess since I know that my code is there i will have to do some serious debugging. Thanks again.